# Documented API for high-level IP/network interface information?

Tags: linux, network-programming

For years I've been parsing the cryptic and undocumented output of `ifconfig`. Now in debian stretch/9, `ifconfig` is gone. One can install it but it has completely different output from `ifconfig` on debian jessie/8. Apparenty, I'm now supposed to rely on the equally undocumented and cryptic output of `ip addr`.

Enough.

Is the `ip addr` output documented anywhere to a degree that allows for reliable machine parsing?

Otherwise, is there some other high-level API I can query to get basic interface information: What interfaces and addresses do I have?

(Not using Network Manager)

Sure, I could write it in C I guess, but then it looses both handy and high-level, as I need it in a scripting language.

I'm thinking something like `ip --json addr` with JSON, YAML, comma/space separated output or something else *handy*, and *documented*, that has a chance of remaining stable for years...

I can't be the first guy to need this... Otherwise its back to regexps against `ip addr` output. Oh, no...

Comment: the `ip` command does have a `-json` switch, giving you json output intended to have a stable interface. Documenation is lacking.

Comment: Ask and you shall receive! :-) I can't believe I didn't try that. I said I wanted a `ip --json addr` and that very thing exists and works. Wonderful! It is, however, undocumented. :-( But way better than regexps.... Thanks, @nos

Comment: Then of course `ip --json addr` isn't supported on my target plaform, debian stretch/9. :-(

Comment: Note it's -json, not --json. though I suppose it's a rather new feature

Comment: Both `--json` and `-json` work here on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: --json not working on Linux 4.12.0 (CentOS) too

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to use the `ip` command because most Linux distros officially suggest to use it over the old (and loved) `ifconfig` . I disagree with this decision but we have to adapt. I have used 'ifconfig' for ages too and now I am trying to get confident with this new command because it seems there are no alternatives. If I am able to find one, I will let you know.